# Can't run tests with debug mode in Laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm, xdebug, mamp-pro

I'm trying to run test with debug mode in my Laravel project.
Tests runs but debug mode fails. I'm using: MAMP PRO 6, PHP 7.4.9, Xdebug v2.9.6, PhpStorm.

What can causes this issue. How to fix it?

During debug mode the following messages occurs:

```
Connection was not established. Cannot start debugger session with
'Xdebug 2.9.6' Validate installation
```

and next

```
Connection was not established.
'Xdebug 2.9.6' extension is installed. Check configuration options. Show phpinfo
```

phpini:

```
PHP version: 7.4.9
PHP CLI: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.9/bin/php
PHP CGI: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.9/bin/php-cgi 
Loaded Configuration File: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.9/conf/php.ini
Debugger extension: Xdebug 2.9.6
Loaded extensions:  bcmath, bz2, calendar, Core, ctype, curl, date, dom, exif, fileinfo, filter, ftp, gd, gettext, hash, iconv, imap, intl, json, ldap, libxml, mbstring, mysqli, mysqlnd, openssl, pcntl, pcre, PDO, pdo_mysql, pdo_pgsql, pdo_sqlite, pgsql, Phar, posix, readline, Reflection, session, SimpleXML, soap, sockets, sodium, SPL, sqlite3, standard, tokenizer, xdebug, xml, xmlreader, xmlrpc, xmlwriter, xsl, zip, zlib

...
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360008194080-Connection-was-not-established-xDebug-PHPUnit-SSH

Comment: @KamleshPaul setting up of deployment server as a remote helped to validate and debug web requests. But cli (artisan) requests and running of tests are still not catches by debugger.

Comment: What is strange that i've checked another laravel project on the same machine, IDE, mamp, xdubug etc and another project test with debug mode works correctly... Doesn't work at laravel is 8.32.1, works is 6.3.0

Answer (score 0):

Changing debug port to 9001 in phpstorm config helped for me.

[image]